# Jenkins failing to send e-mail to group mail Id but works on individual Id

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When my build fails, Jenkins is sending an email to individual email id's but when I am using group id its not sending an email to all the individuals listed under that group.

All the global settings are configured correctly.

Comment: Do you get an error message if you send the test email (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Test configuration by sending test e-mail) to a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email-ext 2.38 is latest version i was using the same and it is working perfectly for me to send mail to a group_id.Upgrade your Email-ext plugin and check.